# Parallel BFS through mpj library in java

Tags: java, mpi, mpj-express

I am currently working on Parallel Breadth First Search in Java with the help of MPJ Express.

I want to know if one of the processor finds the element or node (label) from any of the processors how can I make the other processors stop the further processing.

I am confused about what type of communication is needed there (blocking or non blocking). 
I already use the command `MPI.COMM_WORLD.Send` to traverse the complete graph but I wonder 
when the required data is found, will all processing go to the end?

Which methods are required to perform this function in MPJ?

What will be the procedure to do this?